# How to involve two instances from a different class, python 2

Tags: python-2.7, class

I'm trying to create a Soccer match program for a couple of my friends. What I currently have a class to instantiate teams and I'm writing the match instantiating class.

What I currently have is:

```
class Team(object):
      def __init__(self, name, games=0, points=0, goals=0, wins=0, loses=0):
    self.name     = name
    self.points   = points
    self.games    = games
    self.goals    = goals
    self.wins     = wins
    self.loses    = loses

  def win(self):
    self.points += 3
    self.wins   += 1
    self.games  += 1

  def lose(self):
    self.points += 1
    self.loses  += 1
    self.games  += 1

  def ratio(self):
    print "(Wins/Loses/Games)\n   ", self.wins, "/", self.loses, "/", self.games

class Match(object):
  def __init__(self, teamagoals, teambgoals):
    self.teamagoals = teamagoals
    self.teambgoals = teambgoals

  def playgame(teama, teamb):
    #conditional statements which will decide who wins

alpha   = Team("George's Team")
beta    = Team("Josh's Team")
gamma   = Team("Fred's Team")
```

At this point I run into issues about how to go about doing this. As per my question, I'm trying to - in the Match() class - involve two instances of the team class. For example, I would like to call a function in Match() and specify that team alpha and team gamma play against each other, then when they win or lose modify their instances corresponding point, games, etc, values.

What is the way I can do this? Is it possible through putting all of the Team() instances into a list, then importing that list into the Match() class? Or is there some other, more elegant, way? Please help.

Comment: Partial answer: You can update the team instances quite simply, by doing eg. `alpha.wins += 1`, for example.

Comment: But how should I go about doing that Pythonically? Because I don't want to have to hard code every time a team wins and that would defeat the point of doing it in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you intend to select which teams play each other, but say that's done by one function. Then, Match could be implemented as follows:

```
class Match(object):
    def __init__(self, teama, teamb):
        self.teama = teama
        self.teamb = teamb
    def play(self):
        a_points = 0
        b_points = 0
        # code/function call to decide how many points each team gets. 
        self.teama.points += a_points
        self.teamb.points += b_points
        if a_points > b_points:
            self.teama.wins += 1
        else if b_points > a_points:
            self.teamb.wins += 1
        else:
            # code for when the teams draw
```

I'm not sure how you intend to structure some of the functions, like deciding how many points teams get, but this is a framework that is hopefully useful/gives you ideas on how you could do things.

---

Following up on your comment, if you would like to be able to pass in specific teams created outside the class, you could do so as follows:
`match1 = Match(gamma, alpha)`. This will create a new match instance, where the teams 'gamma' and 'alpha' will be modified. (`teama` and `teamb` in the class will refer to these objects.)

Comment: Using this as a framework, is there a way where I can set teama equivalent to, for example, team Gamma so that it substitutes all of the properties and functions within the team?